# Override Asp Form Action URL Dynamically

Tags: asp.net, forms

I am having problem with overriding Form Action URL

I have a class to override the Form Action.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
       <form id="form1" runat="Server"  action="https://www.test.com">
        <div style="">
            <asp:button runat="Server" onclick="PostMe" Text="Post"/>
        </div>

        <asp:HiddenField runat="server"  ID="test" value="0" />
        <asp:HiddenField runat="server"  ID="test2" value="0" />

    </form>
</body>
</html>





<script runat="server">

    void PostMe(Object sender,EventArgs e){

        RemotePost2 myremotepost =  new RemotePost2();
        myremotepost.Url = "https://www.test.com";
        myremotepost.Add("field1","Tom");
        myremotepost.Add("field2","Sawyer");
        myremotepost.Post();
    }


    public class RemotePost2{
            private System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection Inputs = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();


            public string Url = "";
            public string Method = "post";
            public string FormName = "forms";

            public void Add(string name,string value){
                Inputs.Add(name,value);
            }

            public void Post(){
                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();

                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<html><head>");
                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(string.Format("</head><body onload=\"document.{0}.submit()\">",FormName));
                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(string.Format("<form name=\"{0}\" method=\"{1}\" action=\"{2}\" >",FormName,Method,Url));
                for(int i=0;i< Inputs.Keys.Count;i++){
                    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(string.Format("<input name=\"{0}\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"{1}\">",Inputs.Keys[i],Inputs[Inputs.Keys[i]]));
                }
                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</form>");
                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</body></html>");

                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
            }
    }
```

The problem is I cannot post field1 and field2 instead the form posts test and test2 values. When I use postBackUrl attribute it still posts test and test2.

What I want to do is to post field1 and field2 when the form action is not blank. Because when there is no action it works fine and I cannot modify the action on the code.

Your help will be much appreciated
Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add below to the code behind on load function

myButton.Attributes.Add("onClick", "javascript:
document.forms[0].action='http://otherserver.com/theirpage.html';");

where myButton will be id of your button.

Comment: my mistake, modified the answer

Comment: Thanks, I did it like u said but it still posts test and tes2 form fields. I want to post field1 and field2 what do you think I should do?

Comment: Do you want field1 & field2 to be hidden?

Comment: Alright allright it works now on the test part but Ablecommerce somehow override the onclick function. Thank you very much for you help. :)

Comment: No it didn't work on Ablecommerce, but the test files are working. I'll give you up vote anyway. I can't figure out the problem tho!

Comment: What does Ablecommerce return any message

Comment: It doesn't return any message, it still post other form's values and it doesn't call the  c# function

Comment: I believe there some javascript added on your page which is doing this.

Comment: yes MyButton becomes ctl00_wpm_CheckoutPage_ctl01_ctl18_MyButton When I do      ctl00_wpm_CheckoutPage_ctl01_ctl18_MyButton.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript: document.forms[0].reset() ;document.forms[0].action='';");
It says there is no such button exist.

Comment: In form just update button to have id <asp:button id="MyButton" runat="Server" onclick="PostMe" Text="Post"/> and in code Page Load add what I have given.

Comment: Sorry but the Id changes MyButton to ctl00_wpm_CheckoutPage_ctl01_ctl18_MyButton and it cannot find that button since it hasn't been created. I have to ask it on Ablecommerce forums.